# Padding Empty space in substr in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings with random lengths. I want to print a substr of each string but I want the character length to be fixed like

```
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
{
   source=(namesArray[i]['name']).substr(0,10);
}
```

Now this code works fine it gives me max 10 characters but for those names which are less than 10 characters, i want to print spaces for the characters which are missing. Is it possible ?

Comment: You mean you want to [pad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) ?

Comment: precisely, yes I want to pad those missing characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`String#padEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd):

```js
const str = 'lt10'.substr(0,10).padEnd(10, ' ');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: checking, let me put it to test